# How do I check the results of a chkdsk that ran at start up?

Tags: windows

I already looked in Event Viewer. It was nowhere to be found. Maybe I'm not looking hard enough, lol.

Comment: [Where are the results of the XP Disk Error Checking utility logged?](http://superuser.com/questions/173887/where-are-the-results-of-the-xp-disk-error-checking-utility-logged)

Answer (score 3):

Chkdsk shows up in Event Viewer under the "Application" category under the "Source" column as "Wininit".

See my example below from my Event Viewer log:

[image]

Comment: Oh, so it's called Wininit, not Chkdsk. How logical.